What ranks did the French Garde National have in 1848?
For research on one Frédéric Masson whose father was killed  23 June 1848 as a major in the French Garde Nationale, I am trying to find how high a rank "major" was in that force at that time.  What size of force might a major there and then command?  How many ranks did the Garde have below major and how many above?

Unlike most nationalities, where major is a commissioned rank below lieutenant colonel, in the French army this rank is (and has been as far back as I can determine) the most senior warrant (ie non-commissioned) officer. This rank is likely to be distinguished not by the additional quantity of men commanded, but by the nature of the command or role.
In a modern U.S. Army battalion, the equivalent (Command Sergeant Major) is on the staff of the unit (battalion or larger) commander (and likely responsible, amongst other duties, for ongoing training of battalion enlisted men:

The holder of this rank and position is the most senior enlisted member of a color-bearing Army unit (battalion or higher). ... As such, they are the senior enlisted advisor to the commander. The exact duties vary depending on the unit commander, including observing training and talking with soldiers and their families.

In the context of the question, it's important to remember that (regardless of rank) not all positions are in line of command directly responsible for troop command. Maréchal d'Empire Louis--Alexandre Berthier was Napoleon's Chief of Staff from 1796 until 1814, with authority and responsibility for translating Napoleon's command directive into clear unambiguous orders - yet was rarely (early April 1809 being a notable exception) in command of more than his personal staff. As Berthier modelled, and Clausewitz subsequently formalized for the Prussian General Staff, some of the most important roles in a military unit are those NOT in direct command of troops.
If you are interested in the origin of European rank names, I have previously answered these related questions:

What were the ranks in the army of Imperial Spain?
Why was "Captain" named for two different ranks?
What was the origin of the roles of "lieutenant" officers?
What should I call bands of armed men in the Middle Ages?

For still more about the period, a biography of Francois Achille Bazaine (who rose from the ranks to become a Marshal of France and Commander in Chief of the French Army during the Franco-Prussian War) might be of interest. As Sergent-Major, "he attained the Epaulette on 2 November 1833"
to become a commissioned officer.

Not that I want to nitpick but only your first paragraph seems relevant to the question though.

@OldPadawan: The second and third paragraphs, and quote, specifically address "What size of force might a major there and then command?" Though not part of the titular question, they add specifics which OP provides as context for the question.


Les grades des Forces armées françaises (Armée de l'air et de l'espace, Armée de terre, Marine nationale, Gendarmerie nationale, les services de soutien et les organismes interarmées) et des formations rattachées sont identiques d’un point de vue statutaire et protocolaire, car définis par le statut général des militaires français. Grades de l'armée française (french army ranks)

Translated, it means that the ranks are the same because they're defined by the Statut des militaires français (French military status).
In 1848 (as in 2016, when the name was renewed to design a reserve, both in the military and civilian), the ranks were identical as the ones in the army: Garde Nationale. They're a military reserve force.

What size of force might a major there and then command?

It depends, there are no fixed numbers. A major can be a doctor (same rank, same respect/salute, no men under his responsability, no orders given), a low rank officer in charge of the administration, a commandant waiting to be put in charge of a batallion.

How many ranks did the Garde have below major and how many above?

Ranks are as follow: 2nd class -> 1st class -> caporal -> sergent -> adjudant -> major -> sous-lieutenant -> lieutenant -> capitaine -> commandant -> colonel -> général. In the french army, a sergent has 2 squads, so 30 men, under his command. A major is also second to the colonel (in charge of administrative tasks).

I have followed all links, I still don't see how this actually answers the question? How many men did a major command? Did I miss it in the linked pages?

@nvoigt: it depends, there's no fixed number. A major can be a doctor (same rank, same respect, no men under his responsability, no orders given), a low rank officer in charge of the administration (2nd class -> 1st class -> caporal -> sergent -> adjudant -> major -> sous-lieutenant -> lieutenant -> capitaine -> commandant -> colonel -> général), a commandant waiting to be put in charge of a batallion. FWIW : in the french army, a sergent has  2 squads, so 30 men, under his command. A major is second to the colonel (administrative tasks). Made that more clear in the answer :)
